# What happens if you don't accept M.O.M.'s second mission?

Tags: grow-home

After meeting your primary objective of growing the star plant to its maximum height, you receive a second mission from M.O.M., which you can either accept or not. What happens if you select "NO"?

[image: Screenshot of B.U.D. faced with the decision to accept the new mission]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thanked for your input, but told to do it anyway.